# WebSocket live server

Tags: websocket

Does anyone happen to know of any live WebSocket servers which are accessible over the internet and listen on the standard ports (i.e. 80, and 443). Anything will do - an echo server, for instance.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.piesocket.com/websocket-tester is an alternative and has demo test server like echo.

Comment: None of the options I could find worked so I wrote and deployed my own websocket echo server. Assess it at `ws://websocket-echo-intustack.koyeb.app`. Source code and docker/container images at https://github.com/akostadinov/websocket-echo-io

Comment: And just after I found the one suggested in the websocat's readme `ws://ws.vi-server.org/mirror`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Update**: Kaazing/Tenefit appears to no longer be hosting the WebSocket echo server at websocket.org. An alternative echo server is available at `ws.ifelse.io` instead (running https://github.com/jmalloc/echo-server and hosted by Mark Thomas)

Your best bet is going to be Kaazing's websockets echo server: http://websockets.org/echo.html. It's easy to remember, they keep it up to date and running.

- `ws://echo.websocket.org`   (port 80)
- `wss://echo.websocket.org`  (port 443)

**EDIT:**
If you want to use `wss://` (443) visit the site with `https://` or else use `http://` for `ws://` (80).

**EDIT:** WebSocket.org is dead.

Comment: the websockets server at websocket.org is no longer up - feel free to use https://ws.ifelse.io if you're still looking for this. running https://github.com/jmalloc/echo-server

Comment: awesome! Hope it helps some folks out!

Comment: you can use wss://ws.ifelse.io/ instead of wss://echo.websocket.org

Comment: Try using hookbin.com to create a quick online endpoint. Allows for analysis of the client making the request also.

Comment: https://www.piesocket.com/websocket-tester is an alternative and has demo test server like echo.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily set one up yourself using this simple python script:

https://gist.github.com/jkp/3136208

There is a typo you have to fix: `s/messsage/message/` and if you want it to listen on anything else than localhost replace `"localhost"` with `""`

Comment: outdated, doesn't work with latest python

Answer (score 3):

Can I ask why do you need the standard ports?

If not, you can always use my server, look at http://www.achex.ca to get more info.

Achex

P.S. I will move the server to port 80 in a month or so on address ws://ws.achex.ca